# How do I find Nth term of this pattern?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Assume two numbers **a = 5**, **x = 1**.

```
a = 5   * 1   = 5;     x = 1   - 0.1 = 0.9
a = 5   * 0.9 = 4.5;   x = 0.9 - 0.1 = 0.8
a = 4.5 * 0.8 = 3.6;   x = 0.8 - 0.1 = 0.7
```

and so on…

Is there a way to find the Nth term elegantly? The only way I was able to derive was: (assuming N = 3 in this case):

a * (1-((N-0)*0.1)) * (1-((N-1)*0.1)) * (1-((N-2)*0.1))

…just a scenario in software development, wondering if I could implement a better solution.

Comment: Well if it helps, assuming that $x$ decreases by $0.1$ each time, eventually it will reach $0$, which means $a$ also reaches $0$ at some point.

Comment: $a_n=5\cdot \frac{10!}{10^n (10-n)!}$ for $n<10$ and else 0. Or written directly $a_n= 5 \cdot (10\cdot \ldots \cdot (10-n) )/10^n$

Comment: Awesome, thanks @ctst
And 2012ssohn, sorry didn't quite get how I would be able to proceed knowing that. Would you please mind directing me a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write a recursive relation.

$$a_n = a_{n-1}(1-0.1n) $$
Write out the first few terms and get it in terms of $a_0$:
$$a_1 = 0.9a_0$$
$$a_2 = 0.8a_1 = 0.8*0.9a_0 = \frac{8*9}{10^2}a_0$$
$$a_3 = 0.7a_2 =0.9* 0.8*0.7a_0 =\frac{7*8*9}{10^3}a_0$$ 
So that $$a_n = \frac{9!}{(9-n)!10^n}5$$
However, note that this only holds for $n<10$. If you would like it to work for values greater than $9$, you need to add in a separate recursion, where the difference is simply an absolute value sign and an alternating negative sign.
$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n*9!}{(|9-n|)!10^n}5$$

The $x$ relation is even easier.
$$x_n = x_{n-1} - 0.1$$
Now repeat the procedure above:
$$x_1 = x_0 - 0.1$$
$$x_2 = x_0 - 0.2$$
$$x_n = x_0 - 0.1n = 1-0.1n $$
Consequently, this holds for *any* value of $n$

Comment: Great explanation, thanks a lot!